# Does deleting the objects from s3 using life cycle rules incurs cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have 200M files,for which aws cost calculator  is showing 2400 usd per life cycle transitions.Is this actual or Am i missing anything?Help me guys

Comment: "aws cost calculator is showing 2400 usd per life cycle transitions" show the details that you entered into AWS cost calculator.

Comment: some where i read that 200M files,life cycle transitions could incurr 2.4k usd,and also i have estimated using aws cost calculator

Comment: "and also i have estimated using aws cost calculator" I ask again, show what you did to estimate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deletion of files from s3 is not a transition, it doesn't cost anything.so deleting the files by writing expire object life cycle rules, doesn't cost anything.